# WPF application memory usage

Tags: wpf, memory-management, unmanaged, memory-profiling, unmanaged-memory

I have a WPF application. The memory usage on startup (before additional modules are loaded) is 250/450mb in x86/x64 modes correspondingly.
Part of this memory (about 50mb) is used for resource dictionaries which are stored in large objects heap.
But the biggest part -139mb is consumed by WindowsCodecs library in Unmanaged memory.
Is it OK? Can I reduce somehow usage of the memory by this library?